# Failing Git and Github plugin and its dependency installation in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was trying to install GitHub plugin, but am getting status as failed with error,

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:77)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1139)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git/3.9.1/git.hpi to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\git.jpi.tmp
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1144)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git/3.9.1/git.hpi (redirected to: http://ftp-nyc.osuosl.org/pub/jenkins/plugins/git/3.9.1/git.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1178)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1715)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1978)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have a working internet connection, but couldn't able to fix the issue.

Comment: it redirects to ftp. Looks like a firewall issue

Comment: Could you suggest the firewall settings to be changed?

Comment: firewall configuration depends on your OS

Comment: Mine is windows10

Answer (score 1):

The issue looks similar to [this bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51849) mentioned under the Jenkins Issue. The status shows that this bug is fixed but unreleased.

Check in the comments at the bottom of the page and you can find that it is caused by `firewall`.

Comment: Could you suggest the firewall settings to be changed?